# Cannot append a value to a list from another file using a function decorator

Tags: python

I have 3 python files:

add.py

```py
functions = []

# append the function "f" into the "functions" list. From there, it could be access anywhere
# in run.py by importing this file
def foo(f):
    def wrapper():
        functions.append(f)
        value = f()
        return value
    return wrapper
```

module1.py

```py
import add

@add.foo
def hello():
    print("hello")
```

run.py

```py
import add

print(add.functions)

# run whatever function is at index 0
# the console should log out "hello"
add.functions[0]()
```

At first, when I run the `run.py` file, I was expecting the `functions` list to contain the `hello` function (unexecuted) but it didn't; and it seems like the decorator didn't add that function into the list either, does anyone know why this happened and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

This is the result by the way:

```
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 7, in <module>
    add.functions[0]()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I tried moving the `append` to `foo`; it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(f):
    def wrapper():
        functions.append(f)  # <-- gets executed when wrapper is called
        value = f()
        return value
    return wrapper
```

`wrapper` is what will become your actual `hello`, so the `append` only gets executed when you call `hello()`. And in fact every time you call `hello()`, which is probably not what you want. Move the `append` to `foo`:

```
def foo(f):
    functions.append(f)
    def wrapper():
        value = f()
        return value
    return wrapper
```

And remove the superfluous `value` step:

```
def foo(f):
    functions.append(f)
    def wrapper():
        return f()
    return wrapper
```

And remove `wrapper` entirely, because it does nothing that `f` doesn't already do:

```
def foo(f):
    functions.append(f)
    return f
```

Comment: I forgot to note that this kind of system will be implemented in my project;
therefore, I would add more functionality to the decorator. Also, I tried your code (the 3rd one), didn't work either :(